# Como pasar dos parametros por route en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

Hola amigos tengo un problema y no consigo enviar dos variables por ajax a las rutas de laravel, el error que me sale **Missing required parameters for [Route: checkout.usuario] [URI: reservas/checkout/{id}/usuario/{title}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reserva_barcos\resources\views\reservas\checkout.blade.php)**, la cosa es que los paso como siempre he hecho con un route y ahora mismo me salta el error comentado anteriormente.

**PD: He probado pasandole solo una variable y si que funciona de esta manera:**

```
        var ruta = '{{ route("checkout.usuario",$reservas->id) }}';
```

**Codigo ajax el cual envia dos variables**

```
$("#si").click(function(){
   
    var ruta = "{{ route('checkout.usuario',['id' => $reservas->id, 'title' => $reservas->title]) 
     

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ruta, // This is what I have updated
        success:function(data) {
           
        }
    })
});
```

**Ruta**

```
    Route::get('/reservas/checkout/{id}/usuario/{title}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ReservasController@checkout_usuario')->name('checkout.usuario');
```

Comment: ¿Y si le llegan valores a ambos parámetros?

Comment: sisi que llegan ambos varlores a los dos parametros, no entiendo por que me da este error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los proyectos que desarrollo lo hago así y funciona bien:

```
$("#si").click(function(){
 var id = {{$reservas->id}};
 var title ={{$reservas->title}};
 var ruta ="/reservas/checkout/" + id + "/usuario/" + title;
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ruta, // This is what I have updated
    success:function(data) {
       
       }
   })
});
```

Espero que te sirva.